# Best way to create a Comet/Push webserver?

Tags: webserver, comet, server-push

I need to create a comet server.

What webserver + modules do I have to use ?

Comment: You'll need to give more information than that. What OS? Language? Restrictions on hosting?

Comment: OS linux. Language and hosting doesn't matter... I want to create a simple and efficient comet server. What are the most used technologies used in this case ? Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short list of COMET solution I tried, with pros and cons:

- **[Python Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)**: Non-blocking server based on Python. Unfortunately, "eats" a lot of CPU and doesn't scale very good;
- **[Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/)**: Very good, if you doesn't need to serve more than 10k clients simultaneously. Jetty consumes ~2GB memory per 10k active users;
- **[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)**: The same problems as with Jetty - eats lots of memory;
- **[Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/)**: NIO framework (non-blocking IO). Is not documented very well, and has problems with scaling;
- **[JBoss Netty](http://jboss.org/netty)**: NIO framework based on Apache Mina. Has a weak documentation, as well, but shows the best performance compared to aforementioned solutions. With Netty you can serve ~100k connections at a time, consuming several gigabytes of memory and using ~20% CPU (4-core);

So I strongly recommend you glancing over Netty.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not vote me down, but have your considered about Nginx's push module?

http://pushmodule.slact.net/